# Queue initializing function doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, queue

I am trying to implement a queue using arrays, however my initialization function doesn't seem to work. Even the first line of the function is not executed. Here is the struct, function and main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct queue queue;

struct queue{
    int size, rear, front, length;
    int *arr;
};

queue* init(queue *queue1){
    queue1->size = 2;
    queue1->front = -1;
    queue1->rear = -1;
    queue1->length = 0;
    queue1->arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*queue1->size);
    return queue1;
}

int main(){
    queue* queue1 = init(queue1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must allocate space for your struct first.

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct queue {
    int size, rear, front, length;
    int *arr;
} queue;

queue* init() {
    queue *queue1 = malloc(sizeof(queue));
    queue1->size = 2;
    queue1->front = -1;
    queue1->rear = -1;
    queue1->length = 0;
    queue1->arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*queue1->size);
    return queue1;
}

int main(){
    queue* queue1 = init();
}
```